# Why does insertion command is giving an error about new operator?

Tags: sql, sqlite, sql-insert

I am bit new this, can someone please help me to rectify this error. I am using sqllite:

[image]

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The table name in the INSERT is wrong. And the column list must match the values list.

Try INSERT correct table name   (target columns) Values (vales for each column).

Additionally if you omit any columns the insert will fail unless they have defaults.